# jQuery: Loop through li fading each in then out

Tags: javascript, jquery, delay, fadein, fadeout

I'm trying to have a set of list items fade in, hold then fade out. Thanks to another query on here I have the following code:

```js
function fadeInOut(item) {
  item.fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    if (item.next().length > 0) // if there is a next element
    {
      fadeInOut(item.next());
    } // use it
    else {
      fadeInOut(item.siblings(':first'));
    } // if not, then use go back to the first sibling
  }, 3000);

}

fadeInOut(jQuery('#straplines li:first-child'));
```

```css
#straplines li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul id="straplines">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

However it seems to fade in the first item then stop. Once I place it inside a wordpress template, it fades in the first item which the disappears (not fades out) and stops.

Any ideas on this?

Comment: Could you please add relevant `html`?

Comment: JSfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b2brfd0f/2/

Comment: What do you think first-child in your code is supposed to do?

Comment: @LelioFaieta as I understand it, since there are multiple list elements it specifies the first one to be passed in to the fadeInOut function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to remove the 3000 from the end of your fadeout function:

```js
function fadeInOut(item) {
  item.fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    if (item.next().length) // if there is a next element
    {
      fadeInOut(item.next());
    } // use it
    else {
      fadeInOut(item.siblings(':first'));
    } // if not, then use go back to the first sibling
  });

}

fadeInOut(jQuery('#straplines li:first-child'));
```

```css
#straplines li {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<ul id="straplines">
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
</ul>
```

[Updated fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b2brfd0f/6/)

Answer (score 2):

The last argument you are passing to fadeOut is invalid.

```
function fadeInOut(item) {
  item.fadeIn(1000).delay(3000).fadeOut(1000, function() {
    if (item.next().length > 0) // if there is a next element
    {
      fadeInOut(item.next());
    } // use it
    else {
      fadeInOut(item.siblings(':first'));
    } // if not, then use go back to the first sibling
  });

}
```

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/b2brfd0f/7/

If you had looked at the console you would have seen a ton of errors. I think it was trying to treat it like an easing.

You can see all the different parameter options here.

http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/

This is the signature the code thought you were trying to use: http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/#fadeOut-duration-easing-complete

It always expects that the last argument is a function. But since it had 3 parameters it tried to treat your complete function like it was an easing and your invalid extra parameter like it was the complete function. And I only refer to it as invalid because of its type, not because you can't pass 3 parameters to fadeOut.

Comment: Thanks. Interestingly I was looking at the console and nothing was showing.

Comment: @kaine83 Oh that's odd, I was seeing `jquery-git.js:6683 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery.easing[this.easing] is not a function`. Well glad you got it all figured out. Good luck!